# Test cases shown incorrectly in dotnet core project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I'm trying to create testcases for my tests in my dotnet core project. But resharper shows them not grouped in resharper's "unit test sessions" window

My code:

```
public class Calculator
{
    public static int Multiply(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class CalculatorTests
{
    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> CalculatorTestCaseData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(3, 4, 12).SetName("Multiply 3 and 4 should be 12");
            yield return new TestCaseData(4, 5, 20).SetName("Multiply 4 and 5 should be 20");
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> CalculatorTestCaseDataWithZero
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(0, 4, 12).SetName("Multiply 0 and 4 should be 0");
            yield return new TestCaseData(5, 0, 20).SetName("Multiply 5 and 0 should be 0");
        }
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(CalculatorTests), nameof(CalculatorTestCaseData))]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(CalculatorTests), nameof(CalculatorTestCaseDataWithZero))]
    public void Calculate_Success(int x, int y, int expected)
    {
        Calculator.Multiply(x, y).Should().Be(expected);
    }
}
```

in dotnet core project resharper shows

[image]

in dotnet framework shows

[image]

in framework tests a grouped. I need that in my dotnet core app.

Can anyone help me?

I'm using:

- dotnet core  - 2.1
- Nunit - 3.10.1
- NUnitTestAdapter - 3.10.0
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk - 15.8.0
- Resharper - 2018.2.3
- VS community 2017 - 15.8.2
- FluentAssertions - 5.4.2

**Update**

Case when resharper doesn't recognize my tests

```
public class Calculator
{
    public static int Multiply(MyInt x, MyInt y)
    {
        return x.Value * y.Value;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class CalculatorTests
{
    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> CalculatorTestCaseData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(new MyInt(3), new MyInt(4), new MyInt(12)).SetName("2132");
            yield return new TestCaseData(new MyInt(4), new MyInt(5), new MyInt(20)).SetName("123123asdas");
        }
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(CalculatorTests), nameof(CalculatorTestCaseData))]
    public void Calculate_Success(MyInt x, MyInt y, MyInt expected)
    {
        Calculator.Multiply(x, y).Should().Be(expected.Value);
    }
}

public class MyInt
{
    public int Value;

    public MyInt(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any other nuget packages, maybe a mocking framework? I can't compile the source code, the following line gives me an error: `Calculator.Multiply(x, y).Should().Be(expected);` - _Cannot resolve method **Should**_

Comment: Found it, you forgot to mention you're using the **Fluent Assertions** nuget package :-)

Comment: My mistake, but i think it doesnt matter

Comment: It does matter if someone wants to run your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you have suggestions about difference between display in dotnet Core and dotnet framework? And i need to name my test cases. Default naming is based on ToString, i must override it for all used in test cases classes

Instead of using the method `.SetName()` of `TestCaseData` you can create a test case object and overwrite the `.ToString()` method as follows:

```
public class CalculatorTestData
{
    public CalculatorTestData(int x, int y, int expected)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Expected = expected;
    }

    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    public int Expected { get; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Multiply {X} and {Y} should be {Expected}";
    }
}
```

Using the `CalculatorTestData` object:

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> CalculatorTestCaseData
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(new CalculatorTestData(3, 4, 12));
        yield return new TestCaseData(new CalculatorTestData(4, 5, 20));
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> CalculatorTestCaseDataWithZero
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(new CalculatorTestData(0, 4, 12));
        yield return new TestCaseData(new CalculatorTestData(5, 0, 20));
    }
}
```

And finally, refactoring the test method to use the `CalculatorTestData` object:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(CalculatorTests), nameof(CalculatorTestCaseData))]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(CalculatorTests), nameof(CalculatorTestCaseDataWithZero))]
public void Calculate_Success(CalculatorTestData data)
{
    // arrange/act 
    int result = Calculator.Multiply(data.X, data.Y);

    // assert
    result.Should().Be(data.Expected, because: $"{data.X} * {data.Y} should be {data.Expected}");
}
```

#### Test Explorer - unit tests results:

[image: Test Explorer - unit tests results]

#### Resharper - unit tests results:

[image: Resharper - Unit Test Sessions]

Comment: It is very good solution. I marked it as best answer. But i want to make it work with `SetName`. Your solution is not unified. I must create classes for each test, and in test get data from object. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Im think next fixes in Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk or NUnitTestAdapter will fix this problem.

Comment: @Dias don't get obsessed with `SetName`. Do you want to use it? Fine. My solution sets the test name in one place, using the `SetName` you must set it for every single test case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but using the method `.SetName()` of `TestCaseData` seems to mess up a bit the tests, when using Resharper. Tests were sometimes showing as *Inconclusive*.

In order to group the unit tests correctly (i.e. showing not only the test class but also the test method) I decided to do some refactoring as follows:

### 1) Remove the method `.SetName()`

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> CalculatorTestCaseData
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(3, 4, 12);
        yield return new TestCaseData(4, 5, 20);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> CalculatorTestCaseDataWithZero
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(0, 4, 12);
        yield return new TestCaseData(5, 0, 20);
    }
}
```

### 2) Refactor the test method

I refactored the test method, using the [Arrange-Act-Assert](http://defragdev.com/blog/?p=783) pattern. Test message is now set using the Fluent Assertions:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(CalculatorTests), nameof(CalculatorTestCaseData))]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(CalculatorTests), nameof(CalculatorTestCaseDataWithZero))]
public void Calculate_Success(int x, int y, int expected)
{
    // arrange/act 
    int result = Calculator.Multiply(x, y);

    // assert
    result.Should().Be(expected, because: $"Multiply {x} and {y} should be {expected}");
}
```

### Test Explorer - unit tests results:

[image: Test Explorer unit tests results]

### Resharper - Unit Test Sessions:

[image: Resharper - Unit Test Sessions]

Comment: Thank you for good answer. Do you have suggestions about difference between display in dotnet Core and dotnet framework? And i need to name my test cases. Default naming is based on ToString, i must override it for all used in test cases classes. Im think it unnescessary

Comment: @Dias there are some alternatives, I'll post a new answer soon.

Comment: It's a long-time problem for NUnit that third-party runners are often written based on the assumption that a "Test Name" will always be in the form of a method name or a method name with args in parentheses. That's not so. NUnit itself is entirely agnostic regarding test names.

Comment: Suggestion: try SetName with a value that looks like a method with args.